# Why it doesn't unify? prolog

Tags: prolog

Here we have two predicates
len -> return the length of a list.
processRel -> calls len.

```
len([],0).
len([_|T], R):-
        len(T,X),
        R is X+1.


processRel([H|Q],X):-
        len(H,X).
```

why it doesn't unify?
it returns this:

?- processRel([1,2,3,4],X).

false.

Instead of (my expectation):
X = 4.

The predicates "len" works, I've already tested it, but I don't understand why if put that predicates in another, it works like that. thank you!

Comment: It does unify with the head, but then you call `len(1, X)`, and your `len/2` only unifies with `[]` and `[_|_]`, not with a number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it

```
processRel(L,X):-
    len(L,X).
```

Right now, it is

```
processRel([H|Q],X):-
    len(H,X).
```

Inserting `[1,2,3,4]` means we get

```
processRel([1,2,3,4],X):-
     len(1,X).
```

So it unifies to `len(1,X)`. Which isn't defined because 1 is not a list.

Comment: thank you!! You solved my problem! Another question, why if i wrote this:
minL(L):- len(L,X),
  X<10.
?- minL([1,2]), return false?